# Convert date to UTC and local timezone when sending it with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, axios, timezone

I'm currently struggling to convert a date to utc and then once i get it from the server to local time.

I've a date picker, where i can obviously choose date, as seen here:

[image: DatePicker]

I'm using axios to send my formdata, this is the statement for it:

```ts
const response = await axios.post(url, data);
```

`data` has a property called `create_discoDate`, which looks like this before sending the request:
[image: Date before sending the request]

Once the request is processed on the server, I'm getting an UTC string out of it:
[image: UTC String on the server]

As far as I know, this is expected, since axios converts the date to UTC before sending it to the server.

When I read my records, i get the UTC string from the server:

[image: UTC string from server]

So the next thing I'm trying to do, is to get it back to my local timezone, which is CET (GMT+1).
I'm trying to parse the date like this:

```ts
return new Date(Date.parse(data.DiscoveryDate)).toLocaleDateString(undefined,
                    {day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", year: "numeric"});
```

But the result is:

[image: Result after parse]

Which is one day off.
I really don't know why thats the case.

It would be great if someone could put me on the right track.

Thanks!

Comment: try `new Date(data.DiscoveryDate).toLocaleDateString(undefined,
                    {day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", year: "numeric"});`

Comment: @MisterJojo - that's just a shorter way to write the same statement as they already have.  In other words, `new Date(Date.parse(string))` is the same as `new Date(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem ultimately is due to treating dates as if they were timestamps.  JavaScript is notorious for this - `Date` objects are actually timestamps, not dates.

- A date is `2023-02-01`

  - It can be thought of as the interval `[2023-02-01T00:00, 2023-02-02T00:00)`
- A timestamp is `2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Date pickers that give you back a JavaScript `Date` object are silently assuming you want a timestamp with the associated time to be `00:00.000` in the user's time zone.  In most cases, you actually just want the date selected - without a time.

Some date pickers are smarter than others with this regard.  For example, the HTML standard element [`<Input Type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) just has its `value` property return a string in yyyy-mm-dd format, rather than a `Date` object.

If your date picker returns a `Date` object, the best thing you can do is to create a string in yyyy-mm-dd format and send that instead.  On the back end, most databases have a `DATE` type that is just a date.  Use that where you can, and you won't have any time zone conversions to worry about.

With regard to the sample you showed:

- `create_discoDate` is a `Date` object constructed with the selected date at midnight in the user's local time zone - `2023-02-01T00:00+01:00`
- `discoDate` has that time converted to UTC - `2023-01-31T23:00Z`

  - If you write this to a `DATE` field in a database, you'll only be saving the date part: `2023-01-31`
- `DiscoveryDate` appears to have been created by reading `2023-01-31` out of the database and assigning it to midnight UTC.  Here is another place where you should just keep it as a date.

  - Note that JavaScript will parse `new Date('2023-01-31')` as a timestamp at midnight UTC rather than midnight local time.  (ECMAScript deviates from ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 in this regard.).  So if you really need a `Date` object, you should artifically construct it with a local time, as in `new Date('2023-01-31T12:00')`.  (I prefer noon instead of midnight to avoid certain DST edge cases.)